# LAN web server for testing my websites on my phone?

Tags: webserver

I am a front end web developer.

I would like a web server on my local wifi network for testing my websites on my phone. I am aware that there are several options out there but witch one would be best for quick testing of multiple websites (also a GUI would be preferable)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is pretty complex. You have to create and configure a DNS server then you have to configure your phone to get this DNS, etc.

If your phone is an android the best solution is to use your USB Cable and put your phone in dev mode, then you can debug your site with chrome directly on your phone.

how to: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/

For iPhone i don't know if is possible. But the common solution is to use the simulator.

Comment: is there any other way?

Comment: If your internet modem accept it, you can manually define DNS inner. You have to put your development computer in static or reserved ip, then in your box you point domain name to your computer. And you need to open port in your computer and configure a local web server.

Comment: is that compecated?